# Where can I see deno downloaded packages?

Tags: typescript, caching, deno

I am new to **deno** and currently exploring for a minimum viable project in deno. I want to like npm which downloads the npm packages inside the folder `node_modules`, similarly I want to see the **deno packages** in a directory. In my current project I do not see any downloaded packages. Please suggest me where to look for deno packages. If I write `dep.ts` file to mention all the deno packages, can I use the same deno packages for some other projects. My question is bit similar to what `Maven` or `Gradle` in java handles. It means I want to know whether deno maintains a single folder in OS so that all the packages are downloaded and used in many projects. I want to check the directory containing the deno packages in windows 10.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The imports are cached in `$DENO_DIR`

From the [docs](https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code):

> Deno caches remote imports in a special directory specified by the
> `$DENO_DIR` environmental variable. It defaults to the system's cache
> directory if `$DENO_DIR` is not specified. The next time you run the
> program, no downloads will be made. If the program hasn't changed, it
> won't be recompiled either. The default directory is:
>
> - On Linux/Redox: `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/deno` or `$HOME/.cache/deno`
> - On Windows: `%LOCALAPPDATA%/deno` (`%LOCALAPPDATA% = FOLDERID_LocalAppData`)
> - On macOS: `$HOME/Library/Caches/deno` If something fails, it falls back to
>   `$HOME/.deno`
>
> Relying on external servers is convenient for development but brittle
> in production. **Production software should always bundle its**
> **dependencies. In Deno this is done by checking the $DENO_DIR into your**
> **source control system**, and specifying that path as the $DENO_DIR
> environmental variable at runtime.

You can see the information by running: `deno info`

---

> what is the deno command to install all the dependencies mentioned in
> dep.ts file

To install just [import `dep.ts`](https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code#it-seems-unwieldy-to-import-urls-everywhere) in one of your files and run:

```
deno run index.js
```

Comment: what is the deno command to install all the dependencies mentioned in dep.ts file ?

Comment: I am checking constantly, Really Good and Great Answer. Again +1 and Accepted from my side. I may ask more questions, please bear with me. I am generating more interest on deno and it seems to be more promising than NodeJs.

Comment: Thanks! No worries I'll be happy to answer any questions if I know the answer of course :). I don't know if more promising than Node.js, they're both great IMO.

Comment: I just mentioned `import * as logger from "https://deno.land/std/log/mod.ts";` in `dep.ts` file. When I tried to import in another class like this 'import {logger} from "./dep.ts";', it is not working, it says `error: TS2305 [ERROR]: Module '"https://deno.land/std/log/mod"' has no exported member 'logger'.`

Comment: you have to `export` in `deps.ts`, check example: https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code#it-seems-unwieldy-to-import-urls-everywhere

Comment: Please don't mind, I asked this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800486/unable-to-import-dependency-in-deno-dep-ts-file-in-another-class

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`deno info`](https://deno.land/manual/tools/dependency_inspector#cache-location) to get the cache directory of remote modules.

Sample output (Windows 10):

```
> deno info
DENO_DIR location: "C:\\Users\\ford\\AppData\\Local\\deno"
Remote modules cache: "C:\\Users\\ford\\AppData\\Local\\deno\\deps"
TypeScript compiler cache: "C:\\Users\\ford\\AppData\\Local\\deno\\gen"
```

To get info about a single (remote) module:

```sh
deno info --unstable https://deno.land/std/fs/mod.ts # --unstable needed as of 1.0.3
```

Sample output:

```
local: C:\Users\ford\AppData\Local\deno\deps\https\deno.land\434fe4a7...8f300799a073e0
type: TypeScript
compiled: C:\Users\ford\AppData\Local\deno\gen\https\deno.land\std\fs\mod.ts.js
map: C:\Users\ford\AppData\Local\deno\gen\https\deno.land\std\fs\mod.ts.js.map 
deps:
https://deno.land/std/fs/mod.ts
  ├─┬ https://deno.land/std/fs/empty_dir.ts
  ...
```

`local`: Local path of source file (TS or JS)
`compiled`: Local path of compiled source code (`.js`, for TS only)
`map`: Local path of source map (TS only)
`deps`: Dependency tree of source file

Comment: Was it introduced in the latest version or from the inception ?

Comment: The cache location output for `deno info` has been added in `v1.0.2`, see related [PR](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/5703).