# Unable to import dependency in deno dep.ts file in another class

Tags: typescript, deno

I have mentioned the dependency in dep.ts file and I want to import the reference in another file. But I am getting the following error. Please help me to resolve. I was following the link as mentioned below.

https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code#it-seems-unwieldy-to-import-urls-everywhere

My simple code goes here.

**dep.ts**

```
export {
    log
  } from "https://deno.land/std/log/mod.ts";
```

**Test3.ts**

```
import { log } from "./dep.ts";

export class Test3 {

    public show() {
        log.debug("Exploring deno ...");

    }

}

const test = new Test3();
test.show();
```

While executing the command deno run Test3.ts, I get the following error.

```
error: Uncaught NotFound: Cannot resolve module "file:///C:/javascriptdev1/deno-test1/deps.ts" from "file:///C:/javascriptdev1/deno-test1/Test3.ts"
    at unwrapResponse ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:43:11)
    at Object.sendAsync ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:98:10)
    at async processImports ($deno$/compiler.ts:736:23)
    at async processImports ($deno$/compiler.ts:753:7)
    at async compile ($deno$/compiler.ts:1316:31)
    at async tsCompilerOnMessage ($deno$/compiler.ts:1548:22)
    at async workerMessageRecvCallback ($deno$/runtime_worker.ts:74:9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
error: Uncaught NotFound: Cannot resolve module
```

That error means you're importing the wrong file (does not exist).

You're importing `deps.ts` instead of `dep.ts`

---

Aside from that, what you want is to:

```
export * as log from "https://deno.land/std/log/mod.ts";

// you can have other exports too
export {
  assert,
  assertEquals,
  assertStrContains,
} from "https://deno.land/std/testing/asserts.ts";
```

Otherwise you'll get:

```
Module '"./deps"' has no exported member 'log'
```

Comment: My bad, I corrected it. By the way I have multiple to export, how to do that, do I have write each with export ?

Comment: You're welcome :). Added an example of multiple export.

Comment: Thank you @Marcos.

Answer (score 0):

You're importing from "deps.ts" but the file name is "dep.ts". Make sure everything is spelled correctly.

Comment: I rectified, but I get this error `error: TS2305 [ERROR]: Module '"https://deno.land/std/log/mod"' has no exported member 'log'.`