# Where does Deno keep the `localStorage` SQLite file?

Tags: sqlite, local-storage, filesystems, deno

I've  just read through the [Web API's from the Deno docs](https://deno.land/manual@v1.26.1/runtime/web_storage_api) and seems like `localStorage` is implemented as a persisted SQLite and `sessionStorage` is implemented as a in-memory SQLite.

Whenever passing no `--location` argument, where in my filesystem can I find the SQLite DB?

Comment: May be you should be asking on https://superuser.com/?

Comment: The question is not about programming or an algorithm. You are asking merely about a file location for a particular software.

Comment: @PChemGuy Deno is a JS runtime, clearly seems programming related to me (precedence: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages)

Comment: While I could still argue against, the *sqlite* tag is definitely irrelevant. Just because the target file has a particular format, does not justify the tag. The question is merely about the location of the file, and its contents is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By running `deno info` you get the value for **Origin storage**, which is where `localStorage` data is saved. (See [Where can I see deno downloaded packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61799309/where-can-i-see-deno-downloaded-packages) for more info)

```
$ deno info
DENO_DIR location: /home/foo/.cache/deno
Remote modules cache: /home/foo/.cache/deno/deps
npm modules cache: /home/foo/.cache/deno/npm
Emitted modules cache: /home/foo/.cache/deno/gen
Language server registries cache: /home/foo/.cache/deno/registries
Origin storage: /home/foo/.cache/deno/location_data
```

Inside `.cache/deno/location_data` you'll see different folders for different storages depending on the `--location` flag.

---

Run the following Deno script:

```js
localStorage.setItem("myDemo", "Deno App");
```

Now you'll see a folder inside `location_data`

```
# Replace with the location specified in <Origin Storage>
ls ~/.cache/deno/location_data/
```

You'll get something like this:

```
03c0fe5beae8096bc7bdbe2232281947d85e38f4f95f6397559f30b670cb8549/
```

If you enter that folder you'll get three files:

```
local_storage  local_storage-shm  local_storage-wal
```

You can load `local_storage` file into `sqlite3` and see the data:

```
# inside that folder
sqlite3 local_storage
```

```sql
select * from data;
```

The output will be the data saved by `setItem`

```
myDemo|Deno App
```

**Have in mind that this is for internal use**

Answer (score 1):

According to [Environment variables | Set Up Your Environment | Manual | Deno](https://deno.land/manual@v1.26.1/getting_started/setup_your_environment), this information is stored in `DENO_DIR`:

> - `DENO_DIR` - this will set the directory where cached information from the CLI is stored. This includes items like cached remote modules, cached transpiled modules, language server cache information and persisted data from local storage. This defaults to the operating systems default cache location and then under the `deno` path.

> The [default](https://deno.land/manual@v1.26.1/linking_to_external_code) directory is:
>
> - On Linux/Redox: `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/deno` or `$HOME/.cache/deno`
> - On Windows: `%LOCALAPPDATA%/deno` (`%LOCALAPPDATA% = FOLDERID_LocalAppData`)
> - On macOS: `$HOME/Library/Caches/deno`
> - If something fails, it falls back to `$HOME/.deno`